# set processor in $http PUT request not saving proper data

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, elasticsearch

Relatively new to javascript and angular. I'm using an elasticsearch instance to ingest/index different files. The webapp should have the capability to allow the user to upload multiple files, which will then be processed using the ingest processor and indexed into ES. I'm using angular-base64-upload to extract the base64 data. The following is what I've tried so far.

The html:

```
<div ng-switch-when="upload">
...
    <input type="file" ng-model="obj.files" name="files" 
           base-sixty-four-input multiple>
    ...
    <div ng-show="obj.files.length != 0">
       <button class="btn btn-primary" type="submit" ng-click="ingest()">
           Index All {{obj.files.length}} Files
       </button> <br><br>
    </div>
</div>
```

The javascript ingest() function code in my controller:

```
//Ingesting multiple files
$scope.obj = {files: []};
$scope.ingest = function () {

    $scope.obj.files.forEach(function (file){
        var fname = file.filename.replace(/\.[^/.]+$/, "");
        var fdata = file.base64;
        //Creating the pipeline
        console.log('filename is: ' + fname);
        $http({
            url: 'http://192.168.100.30:9200/_ingest/pipeline/attachment',
            method: "PUT",
            data: {
                 "description" : "Indexing files",
                     "processors" : [
                       {
                         "set" : {
                           "field" : "filename",
                           "value" : fname
                         },
                         "attachment" : {
                           "field" : "data"
                         }
                       }
                     ]
            }
        })
        .then(function(allowed){
                //Indexing the document
                $http({
                    url: 'http://192.168.100.30:9200/my_index4/my_type/'+fname+'?pipeline=attachment', //unique ID for every document, ensures that there are no overlaps
                    method: "PUT",
                    data: {
                        "data": fdata
                    }
                })

        })
    })
}
```

The console logging is just used for debug purposes.

The issue I'm running into is while elastic stores the file under the proper _id, which in my case is the filename, it does not store the proper `field: filename`. For instance, if I upload 2 files called hello.txt and world.txt, ES will store both files with `hello` and `world` as their respective `_id`s, but the `filename` field is often swapped or just generally, incorrect. I've ran the code multiple times to see if there was a pattern, and I can't really seem to find one.

The `console.log`s show that `fname` is the proper filename before the first `http`, after it, and after the second `http`, which is why I'm confused as to why the `set` processor is not storing it properly.

I may not have clearly explained the issue very well, as it's kind of convoluted. Let me know if anything needs extra explanation. Thanks!

Comment: Please show the code for the `base-sixty-four-input` directive.

Comment: I was told that ng-switch creates its own scope, so if I want $scope.files, in this case, to receive the input, I needed to add $parent. Is this wrong?

Comment: Just realized I didn't show that this code is nested inside a ng-switch... edited for clarity.

Comment: The two PUT operations in the loop likely need to be chained instead of executed in parallel. In fact all the PUT operations likely need to be sequentially chained. Also since the code does separate PUT operations for each file, it would be more efficient to send the files in binary form instead of converting to [base64](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Base64). Base64 encoding adds 33% more data to the PUT request and has been known to crash browsers with large files.

Comment: I've edited the code to fix the $parent issue, and also have tried to chain the PUT requests (unsure if I did it correctly). The original issue persists. Also, I was under the impression that elasticsearch only accepts b64 encoded data. This is the sole reason I am not passing it binary data.

Comment: Try to get two files to upload correctly by writing code to upload the two with 4 sequentially chained PUT operations. If that works, then figure out how to upload files sequentually using a loop.